# how to read an entry in a hashmap from SSJS?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have in a viewScope a hashmap stored but how can I read an entry from it e.g. from a computed text in SSJS ?

```
var pm = viewScope.get("person");
var entry = pm.entrySet(); 
return entry.getValue("email")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`entrySet()` is a way for you to iterate your Map. For example:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("one", "1");
m.put("two", "2");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

will print:

```
one=1
two=2
```

If you want to read a specific key from a map it's actually very simple:

```
<xp:text value="#{viewScope.person.email}" />
```

or if you need dynamic (where you would replace the literal value expressed with the quotes with another dynamic variable of your choosing):

```
<xp:text value="#{viewScope.person['email']}" />
```

Comment: I am sitting now in a situation where the reference to the viewscope has become variable. How can I make this computed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114869/how-to-get-value-from-sessionscope-in-radiogroup-for-xpages